# detecting the text of hand written fonts

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, opencv3.0

I need to detect the text on the product

[image: the photo to analize]

I need to extract the text "GOLD WINNER". 
I tried OCR (tesseract) but it didn't work.

Comment: The text is **Gold winner® REFINED SUNFLOWER OIL**. Did this solve your problem?

Comment: Tesseract still needs to be trained on the font you want to identify.  Perhaps your best bet is to see if Google has a service you can use (possibly for money).

Comment: what for? pretty much every retail product has a unique barcode for identification... at least in the EU. there is no need to read the text. and your question is of very poor quality. please read [ask]

Comment: I need to identify the product when an image of that is given. Is there any other methods to identify the text on it. OCR is not able to identify that characters of that font. It's a hobby project I'm working on.

Comment: You are basically trying to do two things at once. You want to (i) locate the text in the image and (ii) determine what it actually says. For the first one use some text detection algorithm. There's at least one in OpenCV. For the second Tesseract won't do you any good out of the box because the pre trained models are for printed text. So you might try letter and word segmentation and try recognition of handwriting or train Tesseract to read this specific font.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you two way for solution;

- You can use opencv solutions like SURF/SIFT, or free ones ORB etc. 
  [Features2D + Homography to find a known object](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html)
- You can try to find font name of your target image and create a new language data using tesseract.[TrainingTesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract)

Comment: im was trying to work on SURF/SIFT, but apparently they are not involved in opencv3.0.

Comment: I made similar application. I tried ORB, Surf, Sift and other feature descriptors. You don't have to use SURF there are many feature descriptors in opencv. Make a search about feature descriptors and shape descriptors. But used both solutions for similar problem before. Both useful for your problem.

Comment: a small exmaple could be better. as im still a begineer in this.